# What pattern to use?: Chain of handlers where next handler needs to know the result of previos handler

Tags: design-patterns, decorator, chain-of-responsibility

I am working on a solution where I have implemented chain of responsibility pattern. All handlers in chain work independently and in some cases based on the input the chain is broken by a handler since there is no need to continue with the next handler. This has been working prefect until a new change request came in.:(

Now I have a case where I need to make a decision based on the result of my previous handler.
Example: We have an object that based on FirstName and Last we build email and notify manager

First handler: Builds Email address (if it does not exists)

Second handler: if email has been created(and is not a new one) we need to notify manager

So the Second handler depends on the action/result of the First Handler

Choosing Chain of Responsibility: Am I breaking the pattern by wrapping the input and add some more data and use it as an input for my next handler?

Choosing Decorator: Am I breaking the pattern by breaking the chain in cases where I do not want the process to go further?

Or is there a third option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I breaking the pattern by wrapping the input and add some more data and use it as an input for my next handler?

Probably not. As long as you maintain the same contract for each handler, you're fine. The input can be mutable and each handler can modify it. That's no problem. The input can also have polymorphic behavior, so you can wrap it with a Decorator to modify that behavior, as long as the Decorator maintains the same contract between handlers.

Answer (score 0):

If I could correctly understand your description,

[**Chain of Responsibility**](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility) wouldn't fit to your work, because each handler in the chain tries to process an object or request. Changing the object during handling it violates this pattern.

[**decorator**](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator) isn't a proper design pattern for your issue as well. It's structural design pattern, but as far as I understand, you need a behavior design pattern.

**[State Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/state)** would make sense in your scenario. According your exam, there are some states

first state: `Building Email address`

second state: `Notifying manager`

and so on

Comment: I think this answer would benefit with some links or descriptions of the various patterns named here.

Comment: the input to handler is the same, all I need to do is update the state of the input value

Comment: @BTownTKD You are right. It's better. I added some links to check out. Thanks.

Comment: @BurimHajrizaj If the updating state is needed it's more likely state pattern is the best one.

Comment: It's not clear when you say, "_Changing the object during handling it violates this pattern._" whether you mean changing the interface or changing the state of the object. Changing the interface certainly would violate the pattern; but changing the state is fine.